# block in lookThere: undefined method [] for nil Nilclass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I can't figure out why ruby is giving me this error. Here is the code.

```
def lookThere
    lookAround = @warrior.look
    lookAround.each do |npc|
        if not npc.empty? and not npc.wall?
            @npcRanged = @npcRangedList[npc.to_s()]
            return 
        end
    end         
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly `@npcRangedList` is `nil`.  Without seeing more code, no one will be able to tell you why.

Answer (score 0):

`@npcRangedList` is `nil`. You probably want to set it to something in `initialize`.

Comment: This is all the code involving/related to the error:

Answer (score 0):

Probably the below way you can handle the situation. I just tried to create one possible way to regenerate the error you got and one probable resolution of the same:

```
class Foo
 def intialize
 end
 def showval
  @arr[2] = 2
  @arr
 end
end

p Foo.new.showval #=> `showval': undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Now If I we write the same class as below,error will not be thrown up.

```
class Foo
 def initialize
  @arr ||= []
  end
 def showval
  @arr[2] = 2
  @arr
 end
end

p Foo.new.showval #=> [nil, nil, 2]
```